# In laravel, how to use sentinel in a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, sentinel

I am using sentinel to manage my roles an permissions but in this project the permissions can be edited by the admin. so I am using a controller to assign the new permissions. however I cant use the Sentinel class in the controller archive I get the error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Sentinel' not found

because of the namespace

my question is do I need to require with require_once all the Cartalyst files or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this namespace to solve your problem
**use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;**